# Beamer handout mode: Disable collapsing for some frames

Tags: beamer

Some frames of my `beamer` contain not only standard `\pause` statements, but also graphics which are displayed on only a single step.

As a result, when rendering in handout mode, not all content fits onto the page.

So I need a way to disable handout-mode frame collapsing for certain frames.

I've tried `\pause<handout:1>`, but as expected it did not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should replace `\pause` by `\onslide{ ... }`, which is able to *understand* `\onslide<handout:1>`

BTW: `handout:1` is for displaying the content in the handout page 1, to *remove* the unwanted content, use `handout:0`

Edit: graphics included by `\includegraphics` can be paused by `\includegraphics<+>` and not shown in the handout by `\includegraphics<+|handout:0>`

Comment: Thanks. Basically the final solution was to replace every <X> by a <X|handout:X>.

Comment: Right, but I find easier to write most of the time <+> or <+-> as renumerate all the things when I insert one item